# jQuery Mobile page jumping to top when a collapsible is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile page with a panel navigation. The last two elements are collapsibles with further menu items. Expanding or collapsing these causes the page to jump to the top and the user has to scroll down again to choose one of the revealed entries.

I tried to surpress this behaviour by executing `.preventDefault()` in the click event of the collapsible div, but the page still jumps to the top.

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Thanks in advance.

My HTML:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="panel" data-position="left" data-theme="a" data-display="overlay" data-position-fixed="true" >
    <ul class="ui-listview" id="main_nav" data-role="listview" data-theme="a" >
        <!-- lots of other items -->  
        <li class="custom-li" data-icon="carat-r" >
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" class="custom-collapsible" data-theme="a">
                <h2>Mein Account</h2>
                <ul class="ui-listview mainNav" data-role="listview" data-theme="a" >
                    <li id="nav_account" data-icon="carat-r">
                        <a href="#" onclick="return ajax_content('settings/account');" data-rel="close">Account Verwalten</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav_profile_edit" data-icon="carat-r">
                        <a href="#" onclick="return ajax_content('settings/profile_edit');" data-rel="close">Profil bearbeiten</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav_profile_interview" data-icon="carat-r">
                        <a href="#" onclick="return ajax_content('settings/profile_interview');" data-rel="close">Profil Interview bearbeiten</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav_profile_pic" data-icon="carat-r">
                        <a href="#" onclick="return ajax_content('settings/profile_pic');" data-rel="close">Profilbild hochladen</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="custom-li" data-icon="carat-r" >
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" class="custom-collapsible" data-theme="a">
                <h2>AGB / Impressum</h2>
                <ul class="ui-listview mainNav" data-role="listview" data-theme="a" >
                    <li id="nav_profile_edit" data-icon="carat-r">
                        <a href="#" onclick="ajax_content('impressum')" data-rel="close">Impressum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav_profile_intervview" data-icon="carat-r">
                        <a href="#" onclick="ajax_content('agb')" data-rel="close">AGB</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav_profile_pic" data-icon="carat-r">
                        <a href="#" onclick="ajax_content('datenschutz')" data-rel="close">Datenschutz</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Custom CSS:

```
#main_nav .custom-li {
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-width:0 !important;
}

#main_nav .custom-bottom-li {
    border-top-width: 0 !important;  
}

#main_nav .custom-collapsible {
    margin-top:-7px;
    margin-bottom: -9px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
    border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
    border-width:0 !important;
}

#main_nav .ui-collapsible-content{
    margin-top: -7px !important;
    margin-bottom: 7px !important;
}
```

Comment: can we see the source of ajax_content()?

Comment: I think your problem is with your onclick ajax return and your href=#". When you click on your link, ajax_content is called, and then href value is called, because onclick does not return false. So your # anchor is called which is scrolling to top. In order to help more, can I have your ajax_content source code ?

Comment: The OP says the problem happens when expanding/collapsing. Everyone here is focusing on the anchors inside the listviews. Why would they have something to do with the collapsible headers, which are really responsible for the expanding/collapsing action?

Comment: @Demnogonis The problem doesn't happen with desktop browsers. Which mobile platform are you testing on?

Comment: @matpop We are currently testing on Android 4.3, Android 4.4 and iOS with chrome, firefox, safari and the default android browser. It also happens on desktop browsers. Minimize the window to the size of a smartphone and try it again.

Comment: @Demnogonis I see now. You too have the collapsibles inside an overlay panel. I think this is jqm WANTED behaviour when you click/tap ANY anchor inside a scrolled panel. However, jqm team should really prevent this when it comes to collapsible headers (maybe it's in the to-do list).

Comment: are you using an internal or external panel?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue ONLY when panel contents exceeds its' height. At this stage, page scrolls to top, otherwise, nothing happens. Please confirm this by testing it on your side. I tested it on iPhone 5 Safari Mobile.

Comment: @Omar Did you see my answer? The problem is [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/831e5657443a31f1199956a989fb5ce12672d15f/js/widgets/panel.js#L171), take a look at the `expand` variable.

Comment: @matpop a link to a github issue isn't an answer. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: @Omar I just posted it as an answer in order to make it more rapidly visible (indeed it was not accepted as the correct answer and it's not meant to be). Do you want me to fix an open bug? Well, for now you can remove that line of code from jqm or override that method the way you prefer.

Comment: @matpop Thank you! I uncommented the line you pointed out and it works now. :) I'll accept your answer, because you found the source of the problem and grand you the bounty when it becomes possible (18 hour lock).

Comment: @Demnogonis Many thanks, I think it's the best we can do until the issue is resolved by the jqm team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an open bug:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7055
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6688

As a **raw fix for now**, a script like this can be placed after the reference to jQuery Mobile source:

```
$(function() {
    $.mobile.panel.prototype._positionPanel = function() {
        var self = this,
            panelInnerHeight = self._panelInner.outerHeight(),
            expand = panelInnerHeight > $.mobile.getScreenHeight();

        if ( expand || !self.options.positionFixed ) {
            if ( expand ) {
                self._unfixPanel();
                $.mobile.resetActivePageHeight( panelInnerHeight );
            }
          //window.scrollTo( 0, $.mobile.defaultHomeScroll );
        } else {
            self._fixPanel();
        }
    };
});
```

This will override the widget internal method (note the commented line) without the need of changing jQuery Mobile source code directly (which is not possible when the framework is loaded from CDN).

Here's a [live example](http://jsbin.com/urOLeLAb/1).

Comment: note this [comment](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6688#issuecomment-27772246) by one of jQM team. Also note that _expand_ isn't `collapsibleexpand` event.

Comment: I had read it already, but it didn't convince me very much, because I believe that `_positionPanel` must in fact be called "in this case", at least in order to "reset active page height". However, those questions concern more github for the final fix. Finally, I'm not confusing `expand` with `collapsibleexpand` at all.

Comment: The problem is caused when inner panel's height exceeds screen height. It adjusts the height and scroll to panels top (0) in order not to cause page to scroll with the panel.

Comment: Ok, but here I'm not actually contributing to the resolution of the jqm bug. Use github for that.

Comment: In this case the scroll is added to the page after we open the panel, what if my page has already scrolled down and then I click on the menu button? In my application it is scrolling the page to top after clicking the menu button after I reach to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @user3519216: This was a legacy workaround. I recommend to take a look to the latest version of jqm, the issue should have really been fixed by now... hasn't it?

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion use "`javascript:void(0);`" instead of "`#`" in href. You can check it this works. If your onclick fail for some reason to return false like an error at run time. This will save you.

Comment: I was suggesting to add return false after each onclick called. I did not know about js:void(0). Thanks for the trick.

Comment: @franchez Your suggestion is also correct but sometime if your onclick create any error at runtime it does not return false then it create issue. Which can be saved using this.

Comment: This is not a problem with the `ajax_content()` calls. The page jumps when I extend or collapse the **collapsible** that _holds_ these links. You can observe the same behaviour when you go to http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/ on your phone, scroll down a bit and expand one of the collapsibles (Table widget for example) in their panel. However I noticed that JQM renders a lot more code for the collapsible (http://pastebin.com/iApwWR02 <-- comparison of the code). An `a href='#'` is rendered for the click event which seems to be the cause for the jumping.

Answer (score 0):

Please add return false; as a final return in each onclick call.

For example:

```
onclick="ajax_content('impressum'); return false;"
```

And finally, instead of doing

```
return ajax_content('settings/profile_pic');
```

Just call ajax_content without return, add a return false after, and move your logic (what return is supposed to do) inside your ajax_content block.

Comment: This is not a problem with the `ajax_content()` calls. The page jumps when I extend or collapse the **collapsible** that _holds_ these links. You can observe the same behaviour when you go to http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/ on your phone, scroll down a bit and expand one of the collapsibles (Table widget for example) in their panel. However I noticed that JQM renders a lot more code for the collapsible (http://pastebin.com/iApwWR02 <-- comparison of the code). An `a href='#'` is rendered for the click event which seems to be the cause for the jumping.