# Panel in jQuery Mobile - prevent background scroll to top

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I stop the background from scrolling to top when I show a jqm panel?

I've tried to use $.mobile.silentScroll to return to correct position when panel is closed, but it's not working that good.

JQM 1.4.0

Comment: you need to do some modifications on jQM.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264509/jquery-mobile-page-jumping-to-top-when-a-collapsible-is-clicked

Comment: For hope it will be fixed in future releases :)